# Regular expression to match - inside a pattern

Tags: regex

I have to match all `-` inside the following pattern

```
"word-word":        #expected result find one -  
"word-word"         #expected result no - find because the : is missing in the end pattern  
"word-word-word":   #expected result find two -  
"word-word          #expected result no - find because the end pattern is ":
```

Comment: Which language?

Comment: sorry, the language is c#

Comment: When you say *match*, are you trying to count the number of `-`?

Comment: i have to replace - in a file for the strings with this pattern

Comment: What's expected output?

Comment: the expected output is after # in the question

Comment: @CristianCarli if you also need to verify the starting `"` which is not mentioned in your question, you can add a lookbehind too: [`(?<="\S*)-(?=\S*":)`](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%22%5cS*%29-%28%3f%3d%5cS*%22%3a%29&i=%22word-word%22%3a%0d%0a%22word-word%22%0d%0a%22word-word-word%22%3a%0d%0a%22word-word%0d%0aword-word-word-word-word-word%22%3a%0d%0a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match all the hyphens between `"` and `":`, you could try it like this using positive and negative [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). The hyphen will be in captured group 1:

[`(?<="(?:\w+-)*)\w+(-)(?=.*?":)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%22%28%3f%3a%5cw%2b-%29*%29%5cw%2b%28-%29%28%3f%3d.*%3f%22%3a%29&i=%22word-word-word%22%3a%0d%0a%22word-word%22%3a%0d%0a%22word-word-word%22%3a%0d%0a%22word-word-word-word%22%3a%0d%0a%22word-word-word-word-word-word%22%3a%0d%0a%22word-word-word-word-word-word%22%3a%0d%0a%22word-word%22%0d%0a%22word-word%0d%0aword-word-word-word-word-word%22%3a%0d%0a%22word-word-word-word-word-word%22)

If you want to replace the hypen, you could capture the word in group 1, and match the hyphen.

Then as the replacement use `$1` followed by your replacement:

[`(?<="(?:\w+-)*)(\w+)-(?=.*?":)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%22%28%3f%3a%5cw%2b-%29*%29%28%5cw%2b%29-%28%3f%3d.*%3f%22%3a%29&i=%22word-word-word%22%3a%0d%0a%22word-word%22%3a%0d%0a%22word-word-word%22%3a%0d%0a%22word-word-word-word%22%3a%0d%0a%22word-word-word-word-word-word%22%3a%0d%0a%22word-word-word-word-word-word%22%3a%0d%0a%22word-word%22%0d%0a%22word-word%0d%0aword-word-word-word-word-word%22%3a%0d%0a%22word-word-word-word-word-word%22&r=%241%7c)

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind that asserts that what is on the left

  - `"(?:\w+-)*` Match `"`, then repeat zero or more times one or more word characters followed by a hyphen.
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `(\w+)`- Match in a capturing group one or more word characters, then a dash

  - `(?=` Positive lookahead that asserts what is on the right side
  - `.*?":` Match zero or more characters non greedy followed by  `":`
- `)` Close lookahead

Check the "Context" tab to see the replacement in .NET Regex Tester.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know in c#, but Javascript example might be translatable:
result = '"word-word":'.replace(/^[^-]+((-)[^-]+)((-)[^-]+)?:$/, '$2$4');

You would have to check whether result is different from original.
If no, nothing was found, nothing was replaced.
Explanation:
String start, then something not "-"
followed by "-" and more characters not "-"
optionally followed by "-" and more characters not "-"
ending with ":"

Then you want the content of the second and fourth opening bracket.